# get dynamic value inside foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter to write a shopping cart system. Tried to research but unable to figure out the way, I want to get the dynamic value "Green/Red/Yellow" in dynamic drop-down list like below:

[image: Select]

[image: Database Table]

Below is my code:
Model:

```
class Products_model extends CI_Model {


    public function get_all() {
        $result = $this->db->get('products');

        foreach ($result->result() as $value) {
            if ($value->option_values){
                $value->option_values = explode(',', $value->option_values);
            }
        } return $result;
    }
```

Controller:

```
class Shopping_cart extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->model('products_model');
        $this->load->library('cart');
    }



    public function index() {

        $data['records'] = $this->products_model->get_all();
        $data['main'] = 'shopping_cart_view';
        $this->load->view('templates/shopping_cart', $data);
    }

    public function add() {
         //If the product is not listed, perform insert

        $data = array(
            'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
            'qty' => $this->input->post('quantity'),
            'price' => $this->products_model->get_by_id($this->input->post('id'))->price,
            'name' => $this->products_model->get_by_id($this->input->post('id'))->name,
            'option' => '' //I want to get the dynamic values in dropdown list and put in to this option array.
        );
        $this->cart->insert($data);
        redirect('shopping_cart');


        }
```

View:

```
    <?php

     //List products
    foreach ($records->result() as $value) :

        echo form_open('shopping_cart/add');
?>

<?php //List the dropdown if value has option i.e color/size/type
        if ($value->option_name)  
        :?> 
            <?php echo form_label($value->option_name, $value->id)?>
            <?php echo form_dropdown(
                    $value->option_name,
                    $value->option_values
            )?>

        <?php endif;?>

<?php
            echo form_hidden('id', $value->id);
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Add to cart');
        ?>

<?php echo form_close();?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And below is $this->cart->contents() when i submitted "add to cart":

```
Array ( [c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b] => Array ( [rowid] => c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b [id] => 1 [qty] => 1 [price] => 100 [name] => T-shirt [option] => [subtotal] => 100 ) )
```

I am running out of ideas try to get the dynamic value inside dynamic loop. Any advises are really appreciated.

Thanks a lots!

Comment: `option` is blank in the submitted data. doesn't matter what you do in CI to read that value - it'll still be blank. you need to figure out why your form isn't producing the form correctly to actually have those color values submitted back.

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for the reply. I use form_dropdown() to present the value, and in HTML it is like 1,2,3 below:

<slct name="Color">
<opton value="0">Green</opton>
<opton value="1">Yellow</opton>
<opton value="2">Red</opton>
</slct>

So i want to get the value name not 1,2,3

Comment: then you'd need to either embed the color name AS the value, e.g. `<option value="red">Red</option>`, or have a mapping on the server so you can do `0->green` translations.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the array of option_values in the controller (so bring option_values as string via Model and declare an array in the controller that will contain the explode(',', option_values) ).

Then use this array as source for 'option'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part:

```
foreach ($result->result() as $value) {
        if ($value->option_values){
            $value->option_values = explode(',', $value->option_values);
        }
}

return $result;
```

`$value` is only valid, in the way you have done this, during the method. It's not saved to the $result. You would need to do something along these lines:

```
$new_result = array ();
foreach ($result->result() as $value) {
        if ($value->option_values){
            $value->option_values = explode(',', $value->option_values);
        }

        $new_result[] = $value;

}

return $new_result;
```

When you are going through a foreach loop like that, you disconnect the $value form $result.

There are other ways to do this, but I think that is the clearest and most understandable.